# Process makes other processes hang

Tags: linux, process, kill, ps

At some point, a number of scripts seemed to hang for no apparent reason. Running them manually still worked. I narrowed it down to a `ps -ef` that hanged. After a number of processes, output just stopped.

Running `strace ps -ef` gave a lot of output, ending with:

```
close(6)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/27306/status", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6, "Name:\tansible-playboo\nState:\tZ ("..., 2048) = 784
close(6)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/27306/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6, "", 131072)                     = 0
close(6)                                = 0
write(1, "ansible  27306 26822  0 02:01 ? "..., 76ansible  27306 26822  0 02:01 ?        00:00:08 [ansible-playboo] <defunct>
) = 76
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/27308", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/27308/stat", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6, "27308 (ansible-playboo) D 26822 "..., 2048) = 311
close(6)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/27308/status", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6, "Name:\tansible-playboo\nUmask:\t002"..., 2048) = 1150
close(6)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/27308/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6,
```

So, I thought, what is `ps 27308`?  `ps` hanged again.

BTW: hanging here means no further output, not reacting to signals (^c, ^z or `kill` from another terminal; sometimes, but not always, ignoring `kill -9`)

So, this process is apparently the cause of all my problems. Let's `kill -9 27308` as root. Now, `kill` hanged.

Even a normal `shutdown -r now` would not work; I had to `shutdown -nr now`.

Does anyone know how a process can get in such a disruptive state? Has it been seen before? How to prevent this?